# How do I assign named-keys to values after a .split

Tags: javascript

I have split a textstring into an array:

```
    var contact = text.split(',');
```

As the text string always contains words in the same order, I would like to assign each word with a key according to their order. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some example?

Comment: Aren't they already ordered? ... `var first = contact[0]; var second = contact[1];`

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet below should do the job

```
var keys = ["firstKey", "secondKey", "thirdKey"],
    tmp = text.split(","),
    contact = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length && i < keys.length; i += 1) {
    contact[ keys[i] ] = tmp[i];
}

console.log(contact);
```